# ISO processing tools for Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

I want to make a live USB of Windiws 8.1 to install on another system. Currently I am running Ubuntu 16 server. Are there any tools for making bootable USB like we have power ISO for windows?

I tried using "Startup disk creator". But when I select .iso image, it returns to main window. Are there any other tools?

Comment: Startup Disk Creator is only for Linux ISOs.